# java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, java-ee, class, weblogic, java-6

Hola un gusto en saludarles, por favor necesito que me ayuden con el siguiente problema, resulta que tengo una aplicación en Java que requiere consumir un servicio de seguridad de una URI especifica, esta funcionalidad la comprimo en un JAR generado desde un archivo build.xml, para luego poder crear un objeto que me permita hacer uso de sus metodos.

Utilizo Eclipse como IDE y la versión del compilador requerida para este proyecto es JDK 1.6_29, y al parecer se genera el JAR bien, incluso lo importo como libreria  en el Java Builpath y la clase donde se encuentra el objeto que instancia el método de ese servicio me quita el error de que la importación de la libreria no se puede realizar.

El punto es que a la hora de desplegar las clases en el servidor de aplicaciones que en mi caso es Oracle Weblogic 11g, el log me arroja lo siguiente:

```java
2020.01.17 09:08:29.902 - ERROR - srvtstrma1.tmve.local[10.164.5.51] - Thread[12] - com.tmv.lcl.runtime.dao.AbstractDAO - execute(90) - java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.tmv.lcl.runtime.dao.AbstractDAO.execute(AbstractDAO.java:85)
    at com.tmv.lcl.runtime.executor.tmve.utilities.AuthenticateUserBSExecutor.executeBusinessRule(AuthenticateUserBSExecutor.java:77)
    at com.tmv.lcl.runtime.controller.DefaultController.execute(DefaultController.java:110)
    at com.tmv.lcl.runtime.controller.tmve.DefaultController.execute(DefaultController.java:29)
    at com.tmv.lcl.services.ServiceBrokerImpl.execute(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor79.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSInstanceResolver$WLSInvoker.invoke(WLSInstanceResolver.java:92)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSInstanceResolver$WLSInvoker.invoke(WLSInstanceResolver.java:74)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube$2.invoke(InvokerTube.java:151)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.EndpointMethodHandlerImpl.invoke(EndpointMethodHandlerImpl.java:268)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest(SEIInvokerTube.java:100)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:866)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:815)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:778)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:680)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:403)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:532)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:253)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:140)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSServletAdapter.handle(WLSServletAdapter.java:171)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.HttpServletAdapter$AuthorizedInvoke.run(HttpServletAdapter.java:708)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:363)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:146)
    at weblogic.wsee.util.ServerSecurityHelper.authenticatedInvoke(ServerSecurityHelper.java:103)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.HttpServletAdapter$3.run(HttpServletAdapter.java:311)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.HttpServletAdapter.post(HttpServletAdapter.java:336)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSServlet.doRequest(JAXWSServlet.java:95)
    at weblogic.servlet.http.AbstractAsyncServlet.service(AbstractAsyncServlet.java:99)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:183)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3717)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3681)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2277)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2183)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1454)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/tempuri/SeguridadWebService_Impl
    at com.tmv.lcl.runtime.dao.core.TConectaWSDAO.encryptPassword(TConectaWSDAO.java:25)
    ... 48 more
```

La clase donde instancio el método del servicio que consumo es de tipo DAO

```java
package com.tmv.lcl.runtime.dao.core;
import com.tmv.commons.logging.Logger;
import com.tmv.commons.tracing.Tracer;
import com.tmv.lcl.commons.engine.LCLException;
import com.tmv.lcl.runtime.constants.tmve.Errors;
import com.tmv.lcl.runtime.dao.WebServiceDAO;
import org.tempuri.*; //LA LIBRERIA QUE NECESITO
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import static com.tmv.lcl.runtime.executor.tmve.utilities.AuthenticateUserBSExecutor.urlSeguridad;
public class TConectaWSDAO extends WebServiceDAO {
    private String urlWebServiceAddress = null;
    public TConectaWSDAO() {
        super(WSTYPE_JAXRPC);
        urlWebServiceAddress = urlSeguridad;
    }
    public String encryptPassword (String pass) throws LCLException{

        Tracer tracer = Tracer.getTracer();
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger();
        tracer.begin();
        logger.info("Iniciando metodo de encriptacion: {0}",pass);
        logger.debug("urlWebServiceAddress: {0}", urlWebServiceAddress);
        try {
            logger.debug("Antes de crear objeto de acceso a SeguridadWebService");
            SeguridadWebService encrypt = new SeguridadWebService_Impl(urlWebServiceAddress); //AQUI ESTA FALLANDO
            logger.debug("Despues de crear objeto de acceso a SeguridadWebService: ", encrypt);
            String operationResult = encrypt.getBasicHttpBinding_ISeguridadWebService().encriptar(pass,"TCONECTA");
            logger.debug("Objeto operationResult: ", operationResult);
            return operationResult;
    } catch (RemoteException re) {
        logger.fatal("Error de ejecuci\u00F3n del servicio de encriptacion: {0}", re);
        throw new LCLException(Errors.ERROR_CONSUMO_SERVICIO.getText(),Errors.ERROR_CONSUMO_SERVICIO.getId());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new LCLException(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        tracer.end();
        }
    }
}
```

Interfaz SeguridadWebService

```java
package org.tempuri;

/**
 * Generated class, do not edit.
 *
 * This service interface was generated by weblogic
 * webservice stub gen on Thu Jan 16 10:30:25 BOT 2020  
 */

public interface SeguridadWebService extends javax.xml.rpc.Service {

  weblogic.wsee.context.WebServiceContext context();

  weblogic.wsee.context.WebServiceContext joinContext()
       throws weblogic.wsee.context.ContextNotFoundException;



     //***********************************
     // Port Name: BasicHttpBinding_ISeguridadWebService  
     // Port Type: ISeguridadWebService   
     //***********************************

  /**
   * returns BasicHttpBinding_ISeguridadWebService port in this service 
   */
  org.tempuri.ISeguridadWebService getBasicHttpBinding_ISeguridadWebService() throws javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException;

  /**
   * @deprecated Use getBasicHttpBinding_ISeguridadWebService(byte[] username, byte[] password);
   */
  org.tempuri.ISeguridadWebService getBasicHttpBinding_ISeguridadWebService(String username, String password) throws javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException;

  org.tempuri.ISeguridadWebService getBasicHttpBinding_ISeguridadWebService(byte[] username, byte[] password) throws javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException;


  }
```

Clase SeguridadWebService_Impl que implementa interfaz SeguridadWebService

```java
package org.tempuri;

/**
 * Generated class, do not edit.
 *
 * This service class was generated by weblogic
 * webservice stub gen on Thu Jan 16 10:30:25 BOT 2020 */

public class SeguridadWebService_Impl     extends weblogic.wsee.jaxrpc.ServiceImpl
     implements org.tempuri.SeguridadWebService {

  public SeguridadWebService_Impl() throws javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException {
    this("org/tempuri/SeguridadWebService_saved_wsdl.wsdl", null);
  }

  public SeguridadWebService_Impl(String wsdlurl) throws javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException {
    this(wsdlurl, null);
  }

  public SeguridadWebService_Impl(String wsdlurl, weblogic.wsee.connection.transport.TransportInfo transportInfo) throws javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException {
    super(wsdlurl,
          new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://tempuri.org/", "SeguridadWebService"),
          "org/tempuri/SeguridadWebService_internaldd.xml", transportInfo);
  }

  //***********************************
  // Port Name: BasicHttpBinding_ISeguridadWebService 
  // Port Type: ISeguridadWebService 
  //***********************************

  org.tempuri.ISeguridadWebService mvar_BasicHttpBinding_ISeguridadWebService;

  /**
   * returns BasicHttpBinding_ISeguridadWebService port in this service 
   */
  public org.tempuri.ISeguridadWebService getBasicHttpBinding_ISeguridadWebService() 
    throws javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException
  {

    if (mvar_BasicHttpBinding_ISeguridadWebService == null) {
      mvar_BasicHttpBinding_ISeguridadWebService =
        new org.tempuri.ISeguridadWebService_Stub(_getPort("BasicHttpBinding_ISeguridadWebService"), this);
    }

    if (transportInfo != null && 
        transportInfo instanceof weblogic.wsee.connection.transport.http.HttpTransportInfo) {
      ((javax.xml.rpc.Stub)mvar_BasicHttpBinding_ISeguridadWebService)._setProperty(
        "weblogic.wsee.connection.transportinfo", 
        (weblogic.wsee.connection.transport.http.HttpTransportInfo)transportInfo);
    }

    return mvar_BasicHttpBinding_ISeguridadWebService;
  }

  /**
   * @deprecated  Use getBasicHttpBinding_ISeguridadWebService(byte[] username, byte[] password)
   */
  public org.tempuri.ISeguridadWebService getBasicHttpBinding_ISeguridadWebService(String username, String password) 
    throws javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException
  {
    if (username != null & password != null) {
      weblogic.wsee.connection.transport.http.HttpTransportInfo httpInfo = 
        new weblogic.wsee.connection.transport.http.HttpTransportInfo();
      httpInfo.setUsername(username.getBytes());
      httpInfo.setPassword(password.getBytes());
      transportInfo = httpInfo;
    }
    return getBasicHttpBinding_ISeguridadWebService();
  }

  public org.tempuri.ISeguridadWebService getBasicHttpBinding_ISeguridadWebService(byte[] username, byte[] password) 
    throws javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException
  {
    if (username != null & password != null) {
      weblogic.wsee.connection.transport.http.HttpTransportInfo httpInfo = 
        new weblogic.wsee.connection.transport.http.HttpTransportInfo();
      httpInfo.setUsername(username);
      httpInfo.setPassword(password);
      transportInfo = httpInfo;
    }
    return getBasicHttpBinding_ISeguridadWebService();
  }


}
```

Por ultimo dejo las partes que interesan del archivo build.xml para la generación de este JAR:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="LCL-TST" default="build-service">
    <property name="src.dir" value="src" />
    <property name="lib.dir" value="lib" />
    <property name="build.dir" value="classes" />
    <property name="rtc.dir" value="rtc" />
    <property name="deployments.dir" value="deployments" />


    <property name="ORA_HOME" value="D:/Oracle/Middleware" />
    <property name="WL_HOME" value="${ORA_HOME}/wlserver_10.3" />
    <property name="JAVA_HOME" value="D:/Oracle/Middleware/jdk1.6.0_29" />
    <property name="javac.tools" value="${JAVA_HOME}/lib/tools.jar" />
    <property name="rtc.domain.dir" value="${domain.dir}/rtc" />
    <property name="lib.domain.dir" value="${domain.dir}/lib" />
    <property name="wsdl.dir" value="wsdl" />
    <property name="wsdl.domain.dir" value="${domain.dir}/wsdl" />
    <property name="tconecta.url" value="http://10.164.5.200/tconecta.services/web" />

    <path id="wl.classpath">
            <pathelement location="${WL_HOME}/server/lib/weblogic.jar" />
            <pathelement location="${WL_HOME}/server/lib/webservices.jar" />
            <pathelement location="${javac.tools}" />
    </path>

    <!-- Servicios TCONECTA -->
    <taskdef name="clientgen" classname="weblogic.wsee.tools.anttasks.ClientGenTask" classpathref="wl.classpath" />
    <target name="external-services-tconecta">
    <tstamp>
    <format property="tmp.time" pattern="hhmmss" unit="hour" />
    </tstamp>
    <mkdir dir="${tmp.dir}" />
    <property name="tconecta.package" value="dpi.ws.services.stub" />
    <property name="tconecta.lib.jar" value="${lib.dir}/external-services-tconecta.jar" />

    <clientgen wsdl ="${tconecta.url}/SeguridadWebService.svc?WSDL"
    verbose="false" servicename="SeguridadWebService" destdir="${tmp.dir}" classpathref="wl.classpath"/>
    <javac srcdir="${tmp.dir}" destdir="${tmp.dir}" debug="on" includes="**/*.java" includeantruntime="false">
    <classpath refid="wl.classpath" />
    </javac>
    <jar destfile="${lib.dir}/external-services-tconecta.jar">
    <fileset dir="${tmp.dir}" includes="**/*" />
    </jar>
    <delete dir="${tmp.dir}" includeemptydirs="yes" />
    </target>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ya resolvi el problema muchachos, la solución fue importar el jar generado en la carpeta del weblogic donde se encuentran las librerias, fue cuestion de colocar el jar en la carpeta /lib, era un error de capa ocho, espero que a alguien más le pueda servir esta información